# List<> of specific class types

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Say that I have a series of classes:

```
abstract class MyClass { }
class MyFirstClass : MyClass { }
class MySecondClass : MyClass { }
class MyThirdClass : MyClass { }
```

I want to do something based on a configurable list of these derived class types, so I want to store the chosen class's `Type`s in a list.  I know I could create a `List<Type>`, but I could theoretically add *any* class to that list.  On the other hand, a `List<MyClass>` would be a list of *instances* of these classes, rather than a list of the types themselves.  I could also create an `enum` with one value that corresponds to each derived type, and have a factory method to create the correct one as needed, but that's at least two more places I'd have to update when I added `MyFourthClass`.

Is there a way to do something like `new List<typeof(MyClass)>() = new[] { typeof(MyFirstClass), typeof(MyThirdClass)}`?  Does the very fact I'm asking this question imply a problem with my design?

Comment: You could work with a `List<MyClass>` and cast to the derived types as necessary. It would be good to understand more about your use case as there may be a better design.

Comment: If you're after a solution whereby the compiler will be able to constrain your List to only MyClass-derived Types, then I don't think that's possible. You could certainly implement a custom List<Type>, that rejects invalid types at runtime, though.

Comment: @TyCobb: I think the OP wants a list of System.Type instances, rather than MyClass instances

Comment: Ah, then yes. It would need to be runtime checking as you mentioned.

Comment: Is this for a static list? I can't imagine it would change much since it is of `Type`. The program could read all of the loaded assemblies and create the list for you on start up based on your requirements.

Comment: I would suggest that yes, the question indicates a design issue.  That said, you haven't told us what business requirement this is supposed to satisfy so we have to guess at whether it does it or not and whether there might be a better way.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - For what it's worth, the overall requirement is something along the lines of "Create an arbitrary number of class objects, chosen randomly from the types of classes in this list, which is populated by checkboxes the user controls"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a generic list of types (`List<Type>`) but like you said, you can insert any type there. The solution I can give you is to implement your own List of types from MyClass, for instance:

```
class TypeMyClassList : IList<Type>
{
    private readonly List<Type> _list = new List<Type>();

    private bool CheckType(Type type)
    {
        return type.IsSubclassOf(typeof (MyClass)) || typeof (MyClass) == type;
    }

    public IEnumerator<Type> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(Type item)
    {
        if (CheckType(item))
            _list.Add(item);
        else
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You can't add other types than derived from A");
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _list.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(Type item)
    {
        return _list.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(Type[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(Type item)
    {
        return _list.Remove(item);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _list.Count; }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly { get { return false; } }

    public int IndexOf(Type item)
    {
        return _list.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, Type item)
    {
        if (!CheckType(item))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("You can't insert other types than derived from A");
        _list.Add(item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _list.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public Type this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _list[index];
        }
        set
        {
            Insert(index, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could do thinks like this that you want:

```
    var typeMyClassList = new TypeMyClassList
        {
            typeof(MyClass),
            typeof(MyClassA),
            typeof(MyClassB)
        };
```

The bad thing is that it will allows to do this in compilance time (the error will be raised on runtime):

```
var typeMyClassList = new TypeMyClassList
        {
            typeof(MyClass),
            typeof(MyClassA),
            typeof(MyClassB),
            typeof(string)
        };
```

Comment: I think this is more complex than I'm willing to use in this scenario, but it *would* be what I would use if I were to go forward with it.  Time to go rethink.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this with static, compile-time type checking. Your best bet is to go with a solution like Raul Otaño's in which you do your checks at runtime.

Why can't you do this? The reason is that C# lacks static *metaclass types*. A metaclass is the class of a class. In other words, the instances of a metaclass are themselves classes. If C# had metaclasses, you could say something like `IList<MyClassMeta>` (or perhaps the syntax would be `IList<meta MyClass>` and the compiler would only allow you to pass MyClass (or its subclasses) as "instances", e.g.,

```
IList<meta MyClass> list;
list.Add(MyClass);
```

I've been wanting this functionality for a long time, but I don't expect it any time soon.